# Conservation for Lagrangian with explicit time dependence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, hamiltonian-formalism

Given the Lagrangian

\begin{equation}
L(q,\dot{q},t)= \frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}-V(q) + \dot{q} t + q
\end{equation}

depending on the generalized coordinate $q(t)$, its total time derivative $\dot{q}(t)$ and time $t$.

1. Is the Hamiltonian energy $H$ equal to the total energy $E$ for this system?
2. Is $\frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}+V(q)$ a conserved quantity?

**My attempt:**

Notice that we can write the Lagrangian as
\begin{equation}
L(q, \dot{q}, t)= L^\prime(q, \dot{q}) + \frac{dF(q,t)}{dt} 
\end{equation}

with $L'= \frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}-V(q) $ and $F= qt$. For $L'$, $H'=E'$ since the potential only depends on the coordinate $q$, and the given quantity is conserved because, in the right variables, it is actually the Hamiltonian (and $L'$ does explicitly not depend on time).

Then, since $L'$ is an equivalent Lagrangian describing the system, I would say that these results are also valid for the given Lagrangian $L$. Am I wrong?

I also thought that we could interpret $H'$ as some kind of canonical transformation and the quantity being conserved in the new variables actually means that the quantity is conserved in the old variables, due to the invariance of Poisson brackets.

On the other hand, I don't know how to interpret the given Lagrangian: the quadratic terms in $\dot{q}$ stands for the kinetic energy, but what about the rest of the terms? Is $V(q)$ the total potential energy? Which is the interpretation of each term?

Comment: @Qmechanic yes! As I was saying, the term $\dot{q}t+q$ comes froms a total time derivative. However, I don't know if I can make conclusions from this.

Comment: "Is H=E for this system?" You need to tell us the meaning of the symbols "H" and "E," which are often synonyms. Does your $H$ mean the Hamiltonian Energy: $H=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\dot q - L$? Does your $E$ mean the Total Energy: $E=T+V$? We can not know unless you tell us.

Comment: "Is $\frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}+V(q)$ a conserved quantity?" Yes.

Comment: @hft Yes, $H$ stands for Hamiltonian and $E$ stands for the Total Energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given the Lagrangian
>
> \begin{equation}
> L(q,\dot{q},t)= \frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}-V(q) + \dot{q} t + q
> \end{equation}
>
> depending on the generalized coordinate $q(t)$, its total time derivative $\dot{q}(t)$ and time $t$.

As explained by OP in the comments, $H$ means the Hamiltonian energy $H=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\dot q - L$ and $E$ means the total energy $E=T+U$

> 1. Is the Hamiltonian energy $H$ equal to the total energy $E$ for this system?

It's a little mushy, since you didn't tell us which term is the kinetic energy and which is the potential, but I will assume that:
$$
T = \frac{\dot q^2}{q}+\dot q t\;,
$$
and
$$
U = V - q
$$
in which case:
$$
E = \frac{\dot q^2}{q} + \dot q t + V(q)  - q\;.
$$

Whereas:
$$
H = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\dot q - L 
$$
$$
= \left(2\frac{\dot q}{q}+t\right)\dot q - (\frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}-V(q) + \dot{q} t + q)
$$
$$
=\frac{\dot q^2}{q}+V(q)-q\;,
$$
which is not the same as $E$. (But see the last section below for a caveat.)

I.e., $H\neq E$.

> 2. Is $\frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}+V(q)$ a conserved quantity?

Yes, it is conserved. You can see this by using the equations of motion generated via $L$. Or you can see this by noting that the related lagrangian:
$$
\tilde L = \frac{\dot q^2}{q} - V(q)
$$
generates the same equations of motion, since if differs by only a total derivative, and further that:
$$
\tilde H = \frac{\partial \tilde L}{\partial \dot q}\dot q - \tilde L = \frac{\dot q^2}{q} + V(q)\;,
$$
which is conserved for the usual reasons. (Namely that $\frac{d \tilde H}{dt} = -\frac{\partial \tilde L}{\partial t}=0$.)

> **My attempt:**

> Notice that we can write the Lagrangian as
> \begin{equation}
> L(q, \dot{q}, t)= L^\prime(q, \dot{q}) + \frac{dF(q,t)}{dt} 
> \end{equation}
>
> with $L'= \frac{\dot{q}^2}{q}-V(q) $ and $F= qt$. For $L'$, $H'=E'$ since the potential only depends on the coordinate $q$, and the given quantity is conserved because, in the right variables, it is actually the Hamiltonian (and $L'$ does explicitly not depend on time).
>
> Then, since $L'$ is an equivalent Lagrangian describing the system, I would say that these results are also valid for the given Lagrangian $L$. Am I wrong?

Not *all* the results are *necessarily* the same. But the equations of motions are the same.

> I also thought that we could interpret $H'$ as some kind of canonical transformation

It's not a "canonical transformation." It is the Hamiltonian for the Lagrangian $L'$. If you want to call it something, you could call it a Legendre transformation of the Lagrangian.

> and the quantity being conserved in the new variables actually means that the quantity is conserved in the old variables, due to the invariance of Poisson brackets.

You didn't change variables. The variables are still $q$ and $\dot q$. But, since the equations of motion generated by $L$ and $\tilde L$ are the same then the conserved quantity $\tilde H$ is conserved regardless of which Lagrangian you use to generate your equations of motion.

> On the other hand, I don't know how to interpret the given Lagrangian: the quadratic terms in $\dot{q}$ stands for the kinetic energy, but what about the rest of the terms? Is $V(q)$ the total potential energy? Which is the interpretation of each term?

We can give you no definite interpretation unless you provide more information. The *kinetic* energy is usually quadradic in the velocity, so this might motivate you to say, in contrast to what I did above, that
$$
T = \frac{\dot q^2}{q}
$$
and then the form of the potential $U$ follows from the Lagrangian.

Or you could define, like I did above,
$$
T=\frac{\dot q^2}{q}+\dot q t\;.
$$

---

More generally, you could define
$$
T = \frac{\dot q^2}{q} + a\dot q t + b q
$$
$$
U = V + (a - 1)\dot q t + (b - 1)q\;,
$$
where, a and b can be any real numbers since, regardless,
$$
T - U = \frac{\dot q^2}{q} - V +\dot q t + q = L\;.
$$
And therefore, regardless of a and b:
$$
H = \frac{\dot q^2}{q}+V(q)-q
$$
In any case, we have $H \neq E$, unless a=1/2 and b=0 (which seems like a bit of an odd choice), since
$$
E = T + U =
\frac{\dot q^2}{q} + a\dot q t + b q
+V + (a - 1)\dot q t + (b - 1)q
$$
$$
=\frac{\dot q^2}{q} 
+V + (2a - 1)\dot q t + (2b - 1)q
$$